# Distribute 2 IOS app (to 2 different region

Tags: ios, version, app-store-connect, region

I have an app in the store that distributed to 2 region(IL and AU)
I want to push another app (new version) only to one region  (IL)
But, I want the old version stay in AU region
How can I do it??

I am affraid to try
It looks like Apple (and Android) doesnt allot 1 app with 2 diffrent version

Comment: If they are really two different apps (that is, two different bundle IDs, with two different App Store Connect entries with different regional availability) then you simply update one and not the other. If it is just one app available in two regions then you can't update just one region